# How to use an Swift object method as a closure?

Tags: swift, closures

I'd like to use an object method as a closure because I need to reuse the same closure multiple times in different places in an object. Let's say I have the following:

```
class A {
    func launch(code: Int) -> Bool { return false }
}
```

And I need a closure that is of type `Int -> Bool` in the same object. How would I be able to use the `launch` method as the closure? I'd rather not do something like `{ self.launch($0) }` if I can just directly reference the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Instance methods are curried functions](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/) which take the instance
as the first argument. Therefore

```
class A {
    func launch(code: Int) -> Bool { return false }
    
    func foo() {
        let cl = A.launch(self) 
        // Alternatively:
        let cl = type(of: self).launch(self)

        // ...
    }
}
```

gives you a closure of the type `Int -> Bool`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Is there a way to avoid having to explicitly name the class?

Comment: note that `A.launch` and `self.dynamicType.launch` are not necessarily the same

Comment: @newacct: I also thought that initially, but then I verified that both behave identically even if `launch` is overridden in a subclass. Do you know other differences?