# How to pass an instance method as a closure argument to another function?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to pass an object method as a parameter to another function which is expecting a closure of same signature. I have had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34007809/how-to-use-an-swift-object-method-as-a-closure) without any success.

```
// these are just dummy protocols to make my example run in Playground without include Alamofire or SwiftyJSON
public struct Response<Value, Error: ErrorType> { }
public protocol SwiftyJSONSerializable { }
public protocol ResponsePathProvider { }


class MyClass1 {
    func responseObject<T:SwiftyJSONSerializable>(keyPath path:String, completionHandler: Response<[String:T], NSError> -> Void) -> Self {
        return self
    }
}

class MyClass2 {
    func test() {
        let mc = MyClass1()
        mc.responseObject(keyPath: "/*/", completionHandler: testable) //fails
        mc.responseObject(keyPath: "/*/", completionHandler: self.dynamicType.testable(self)) //fails
    }

    func testable<T:SwiftyJSONSerializable>(response: Response<[String:T], NSError> -> Void) {
        //NOOP
    }
}
```

Comment: first, the " -> Void" is on the wrong side of the ")" (and unnecessary), but messing around a bit, I think the issue is the generic isn't possible to pin down.

Comment: I omitted the `-> Void` of func testable. I can write it as `func testable<T:SwiftyJSONSerializable>(response: Response<[T:SwiftyJSONSerializable], NSError> -> Void) -> Void { }` to make it more clear

Comment: that will cause response to be a function, rather than a type.

Answer (score 1):

First, the testable function should be:

```
func testable<T:SwiftyJSONSerializable>(response: Response<[String:T], NSError>) {
    //NOOP
}
```

to properly adhere to the types.

Unfortunately, I believe this is either a current limitation of generics as they relate to protocols, or a bug. If you simply change SwiftyJSONSerializable to a Class, it works.